Calling wasm code from rust through wasm-bindgen
I have inherited a .wasm binary that was initially compiled from Rust with wasm-bindgen. I need to call this binary from Rust. For this sake, I'm using wasmtime.
I have dutifully bound all the exports, but I'm struggling a bit with the imports, as there's lots of JS code generated by wasm-bindgen that doesn't quite fit how Rust works, e.g.
    imports.wbg.__wbg_set_327aa1a19c3f2018 = function(arg0, arg1, arg2) {
        // By disassembling the wasm, I know that `arg0`, `arg1` and `arg2`
        // are `i32`, but I have no clue of the type of `getObject(arg0)`
        // or that of `takeObject(arg1)`.

        // By the way, `getObject` and `takeObject` are part of a reimplementation
        // of a heap.
        getObject(arg0)[takeObject(arg1)] = takeObject(arg2);
    };

And some of these functions are much more complex, e.g. the auto-generated passStringToWasm0 looks like this.
On the upside, it looks like all this code is pretty much boilerplate, that could be part of a crate.
Does anyone know of a crate that implements all this boilerplate or of a tool that could auto-generate that code?

wasm-bindgen exports JS function, and wasm-bindgen can call JS functions, so all you need to do is to call those exported functions as if they were coming from JS.

I have no difficulties with the exported functions. I have difficulties with the imported ones.

Ahh, now I see that you're using wasmtime (i.e. no JS). I don't know if this is possible. wasm-bindgen was created with interop with JS in mind, not with other WASM files. Is there any chance you can modify & recompile the wasm code?

I suppose I could disassemble, modify and reassemble it, but that feels a tad risky.
